# PHP imap_headerinfo check if exists

Tags: php

I am using the PHP function `imap_open` with this to get the headers of each email:

```
$header=imap_headerinfo($inbox,$email_number);
```

i then run a foreach loop on the CC'd email addresses:

```
foreach ($header->cc as $cc_extra) {

}
```

how can i check if there is anything in `$header->cc` before i run the foreach loop?

**Note:** 
- the `$inbox` is the connection string for the mailbox
- the `$email_number` is the email number for each email

Comment: possible duplicate of [cleanest way to skip a foreach if array is empty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446538/cleanest-way-to-skip-a-foreach-if-array-is-empty)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a combination of [`isset`](http://php.net/isset) and [`is_array`](http://php.net/is_array) like so:

```
$header=imap_headerinfo($inbox,$email_number);
// ...
if(isset($header->cc) && is_array($header->cc)) {
  foreach ($header->cc as $cc_extra) {
  }
}
```

`isset` will test that the variable has been set as is not `null`.
`is_array` will test that the variable is actually an [array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

**EDIT**

Alternatively, as seen in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3446557/1095946), you can explicitly cast the variable as an array inside your `foreach`, e.g.,

```
foreach ((array)$header->cc as $cc_extra) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use next code:

```
$connection = imap_open("{192.168.1.170:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX", $send_from_our, $send_from_pass) or die('Cannot connect to your sever: ' . imap_last_error());
$emails = imap_search($connection, 'UNSEEN');
$unread = 0;
$count = imap_num_msg($connection);

for ($msgno = 1; $msgno <= $count; $msgno++) {
    $cc='';
    $to='';
    $headers = imap_headerinfo($connection, $msgno);           
    if ($headers->Unseen == 'U') {
        $unread++;
        if (isset($headers->cc) && is_array($headers->cc)) {
            foreach ($headers->cc as $cc_extra) {
                $mailbox_cc=strtolower($cc_extra->mailbox);
                $host_cc=strtolower($cc_extra->host);
                $cc .= $mailbox_cc . "@" . $host_cc .',';
            }
            $cc= rtrim($cc, ',');
        }
        if (isset($headers->to) && is_array($headers->to)) {
            foreach ($headers->to as $to_extra) {
                $mailbox_to=strtolower($to_extra->mailbox);
                $host_to=strtolower($to_extra->host);
                if ($mailbox_to=='$MY_EMAIL_NAME' and $host_to='$MY_HOST_NAME') {
                    continue;
                }
                $to .=$mailbox_to . "@" . $host_to.',';
            }
            $to=rtrim($to, ',');
        }
        $fromaddr = $headers->from[0]->mailbox . "@" . $headers->from[0]->host;
        $full_reply_to=rtrim($fromaddr.','.$cc.','.$to, ',');
```

This code recieve all unread email from maibox, and put all adress from CC and TO (exclude my self address) for each email to $full_reply_to